# Applying gravity to a bouncing ball

Tags: java, gravity

I'm working on a bouncing ball program. I have successfully made a ball that goes up and down. I have set so that the ball are unable to go out of bounds so when it hits the edge of the screen, it simply bounces back up and so on.

Now, the thing is, I want the ball to eventually stop moving. For example, I start the program, the ball drops and bounces back up to maybe 80% of it's starting height. And when it comes down again it will accelerate due to gravity and then go back up but maybe only reach about 60% of it's original height, and eventually it will stop moving.

How do I create such a thing? I've googled for hours but found nothing of help. So now I implore you to give me a hand. Also, if you do decide to give me a handy tip, please try to be specific and very clear. I have not been programming for that long. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

EDIT: OBSERVE that I don't have a main method for this class since I don't need it. I'm running it through another class via an object.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    int DIAMETER = 40;
    int yPos;
    int yVel = 3;
    int GRAVITY =1;

    Timer tm = new Timer(5,this);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Setting the characteristics for the ball
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(0, yPos, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
        tm.start();
        repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //If it decides to go out of the screen, change direction.
        if(yPos<0 || yPos>430)yVel=-yVel;

        //This basically is the "engine". It moves the ball.
        yPos = yPos + yVel;

    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.eng.mu.edu/~nagurka/NagurkaHuang_MassSpringDamperModelBouncingBall_ACC04.pdf

Comment: The concept you're referring to is called elastic collisions, look it up you'll know what do to apply physics equation to your simulation

Comment: No, it's definitely inelastic.

Comment: its the same thing, the coefficient of elasticity is just 0

Comment: @MangO_O: I don't think ["coefficient of elasticity"](https://www.google.com/search?q=coefficient+of+elasticity) means what you think it does, and if whatever you mean to talk about were 0, that would probably be a perfectly inelastic collision. This is not a perfectly inelastic collision.

Answer (score 2):

Take some *energy* out of the system.

Just as it hits the ground, the kinetic energy is `E = 0.5 * m * v * v` where `m` is the mass and `v` the speed.

Reduce `E` by a certain amount, say `new_E = 0.8 * E`. Then compute the new initial upward speed using the kinetic energy formula rearranged.

That is surprisingly realistic. Of course, you don't really need the 0.5 coefficient but I've retained it there to keep the physicists happy. You also don't need `m` either.

Comment: And since `E = mgh` this should actually give a precisely 80% height reduction on each bounce.

Comment: Yeah that's very helpful! I will definitely do that! But I just wonder, how do I tell Java to reduce E after a bump? I suppose I could write something like: if ball hits wall reduce energy. But how would I express that in code?

Comment: This can all be simplified to "multiply velocity by a constant". The more pressing difficulty seems to do with translating thought into code.

Comment: @user2357112 Not quite, since the velocity term is squared.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi: That just means the constant is the square root of whatever you multiplied energy by.

Comment: I like to think of it in terms of `v` since then you can apply `s = vt - 0.5gtt` to get the displacement up to the maximum (on the upward movement). 'tis better in floating point to work on an absolute height `s`. That said though, in this case, I doubt precision matters too much.

Comment: Actually guys, this didn't solve it. I don't know how to apply it. How do I tell Java that I wanna do something when the ball hits the ground? How could I possibly describe that in code?

Comment: You're more likely to get a full answer if you offer a bounty. But you'll need to acquire some rep first. The quickest way is to answer some questions. But you can also make small gains by editing questions.